# I accidentally left a crude, personally-insulting debug print line in a public pull request

Tags: source-code, etiquette

It was left there for four hours before I discovered it. Obviously, I fixed that with a force push.

What else can I (or should I) do?

Comment: Please forgive the edit; I was a little surprised to see that language show up on our main page, and I thought it best it should not.  That said, I completely see why you quoted it, and I do hope you get a satisfactory answer to your question.  I suspect the answer will depend on the *mores* of the specific community; could you perhaps tell us which project or codebase you were contributing to?

Answer (score 7):

Different projects have different etiquette and different social contracts, so YMMV. Personally, I'd comment on the PR and apologize with something down the lines of "the previous version of this MR contained inappropriate language that was expressed out of frustration. It was never meant to be pushed publically and I apologize to anyone who found it offensive."

Answer (score 2):

Nothing. Just remove it. If anyone complains about it, just say you've removed it now.